# EXTRA_DIST for Makefile.am repeats the directory name

Tags: c++, c, makefile, automake

I'm using EXTRA_DIST within a Makefile.am to copy some folders:
EXTRA_DIST = input/

The problem is that it repeats the directory name input/input/

Do you know any solution for this problem? is this a bug of automake?

Comment: I have found the solution. With: "EXTRA_DIST = input" instead of "EXTRA_DIST = input/" works fine

Comment: Write that as an answer to your question and then mark it as answered.

Comment: @Jack done! and thanks I'm new here

Comment: Thanks for doing that. You'll do well here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. With: "EXTRA_DIST = input" instead of "EXTRA_DIST = input/" works fine